# Exporting Jacoco*.exec files to Sonar without Maven or ANT or Jenkins

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I don't know if this has been asked before; from a quick search I couldn't find anything relevant, but please do forgive me if I've missed it.

My question is we need to send the jacoco.exec output file to Sonar without using any other tool like Jenkins etc.

Below are the steps we did to configure Jenkins & Sonar

1. Jacoco agent code is setup and injected into our Application server (with WAS Console)
2. SonarQube is installed and configured in another server
3. When we perform manual execution on the application, jacoco is generating a Jacoco*.exec output files (File is in binary format)

Our challenge is how do we send this output file to Sonar, such that it reads and generates reports in a readable format?

PS. When integrated this with Jenkins and Maven, we are able to export this report to Sonar and see the reports properly. But, without using Jenkins and Maven, is there a way to export the Jacoco.exec file to Sonar and generate the reports??

Hope I am clear with my question. Please respond if any part of the question is not clear. 
Thanks in advance for ur help!!

Comment: What does your Maven analysis command look like in Jenkins? Can you just execute the same from the command line?